# Matlab power function randomly malfunctions

Tags: matlab, exponential

```
tk=linspace(0,1,101);
R = 35.9; L = 3.98; C = 0.000360; P = ceil(R/(2*L));
M = ceil(sqrt( (1/(L*C)) - ( (R^2)/ (4*(L^2)) )));
syms q(t);
syms i(t);
q(t) = 40*exp((-R/(2*L))*t).*cos(t*sqrt((1/(L*C))-((R^2)/(4*L^2))));
i(t) = diff(q);
exact_intensity_values = 1:101;
aux = 1:101;
for ix = 1:101
    exact_intensity_values(ix) = i(tk(ix));
    disp('exact intensity value');
    disp(exact_intensity_values(ix));
    aux(ix) = (exact_intensity_values(ix))^(-1/(P * tk(ix)));
    disp('aux value exact');
    disp((aux(ix))^(-P * tk(ix)));
end
```

So, sometimes the two values displayed are the same, as it is supposed to be,  but sometimes they are very different. What am I doing wrong?

Here are some examples, I won't post all of them. Usually when the exact intensity value is negative the aux value is its symmetric, as in the same absolute value but positive. Other times the numbers have nothing to do with each other. Other times they are the same. I'm completely lost, I've been debugging this for a long time now.

This one is for tk(ix) = 0. It makes no sense whatsoever.

exact intensity value 
-180.4020

aux value exact 
1

Edit - Now that I think about it a bit more it probably makes sense, since tk(1) = 0 we have `exact_intensity_values(ix)^(-1/0)`, and that probably causes the problems here. This can probably be safely ignored.

These ones have the correct absolute value, but incorrect sign.

exact intensity value
 -422.8061

aux value exact
  422.8061

exact intensity value
 -616.2485

aux value exact
  616.2485

These ones are correct:
exact intensity value
  464.3460

aux value exact
  464.3460

exact intensity value
  412.2708

aux value exact
  412.2708

exact intensity value
  337.3326

aux value exact
  337.3326

exact intensity value
  246.4757

aux value exact
  246.4757

These ones have a negative exact value but are correct:

exact intensity value
  -48.4391

aux value exact
 -48.4391 + 0.0000i

exact intensity value
 -132.0104

aux value exact
  -1.3201e+02 + 2.2673e-14i

exact intensity value
 -199.6144

aux value exact
  -1.9961e+02 + 6.9122e-14i

I can't see any pattern in what causes some values to be correct and others incorrect, it seems absolutely random. I've tried both ^ and the power function but the results are exactly the same...

MATLAB Version: 9.5.0.944444 (R2018b)

Edit #2: So the values are only incorrect for the first values of the curve. Here are the graphs, the first one has all the correct values and the second one has the incorrect values as well as some correct.
[image]

[image]

Comment: The formatting of this question makes it really hard to read (I doubt anyone is going to actually read the exact/intensity value stream you've listed). You've also not said which is your expected result... Try editing the question to improve this if you want a good answer.

Comment: @Wolfie I've figured out the problem. Not this problem, but turns out I was misreading what I had to do and this problem was no longer relevant to what I wanted to do.

Comment: OK... consider providing an answer for future readers with the same problem, and so this question can be marked as closed.

Answer (score 1):

I know you said that you solved this problem, but I'm providing this answer so that the question doesn't remain unanswered.

It appears that the "very different" values simply have a *small* imaginary component. Otherwise, the real part appears to be the same (within numerical error), and only the notation is different (which is likely the default display format for complex doubles):

- `-1.3201e+02` likely means the same as `-132.0104`.
- `-1.9961e+02` likely means the same as `-199.6144`.
- `0.0000i`, `2.2673e-14i` and `6.9122e-14i` mean `0` *practically*, but **not** *numerically*.

I would advise to surround values that should be real with [`real()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/real.html).

See also: [Why is 24.0000 not equal to 24.0000 in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/)